# Windows Update - hide unneeded updates

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update

Imagine a situation - one installs *Visual Studio 2012*, uses it, installs all needed updates (the updates for other Microsoft products active in Windows Update) and so on.

Then here comes *Visual Studio 2013* and you simply change to it and stop using the older software.

Yet, there still are old updates for software now completely uninstalled.

How can I get rid of those updates which still show in **Windows Update**?

I'm trying to do it at a Windows 8.1 x64 and the problem is exactly with the old *Visual Studio 2010* updates that still are on my hard drive.

Comment: I think when you remove VS2012, it should take care of updates..I am not sure though...

Comment: @tumchaaditya nope, I had installed both VS 2010 and 2012, now 2013 is on board and I don't need 2010 so I uninstalled it completely with all its' components. Yet, Windows Update still shows update for it.

Comment: Ohh ok..Nice to know..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Visual Studio 2012 does not use Windows Update for VSUpdate. What you are seeing in Window Update are most likely updates for .NET Framework.

For Visual Studio 2010, you may need to manually remove the detection keys in the registry: [Detection keys for .NET Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/detection-keys-for-net-framework-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: Oh, that's good to know! But about the registry keys, one thing is to locate them another is to delete them, is this safe? I mean, what can possibly crash after such a deletion ;) an thanks for the link!

Comment: You can always make a backup of the registry before deletion. Since it is VS specific registry, nothing apart from VS could possibly crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide updates by right-clicking them.

YOu can restore them by clicking on the "retore hidden update" link.

Comment: You are just hiding them, what I meant is to completely delete them. It's not the same.

Comment: The list isn't locally stored.